# How to lowercase only the first character of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I would like to be able to change the first character of a string to be sure it will be lowercase.

How can I do that?

For example, <kbd>Hello World</kbd><kbd>-></kbd><kbd>hello World</kbd>

Comment: You might want to use an example that includes uppercase characters in the output.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I want to convert ONLY first letter to downcase. It's better to create a new string with the desired property

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way:

```
str = "Hello World"
str[0] = str[0].downcase
str #=> "hello World"
```

Comment: Not `downcase!` (recognizing that it returns `nil` if the first letter is lower case)?

Comment: Way more concise than mine. I love this solution.

Answer (score 6):

```
def downcase_first_letter(str)
  str[0].downcase + str[1..-1]
end

puts downcase_first_letter('Hello World') #=> hello World
```

Answer (score 4):

```
'foo_bar_baz'.camelize(:lower)          # => "fooBarBaz"
'active_record/errors'.camelize(:lower) # => "activeRecord::Errors"
```

reference: https://makandracards.com/makandra/24050-ruby-how-to-camelize-a-string-with-a-lower-case-first-letter

Comment: How is this answer at the bottom!

Comment: The question was about the implementation with the Ruby language, not the Ruby dialect of Rails.

Comment: Unexpectedly this answer has a high rating, because in addition to lowering the first character, camelize(:lower) does many other changes to the string (it removes `_` , replaces `::` and can uppercase many characters) 
`'active_record'.camelize(:lower) # => "activeRecord"`
`'active_record/errors'.camelize(:lower) # => "activeRecord::Errors"`
[api.rubyonrails camelize](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-camelize)

Comment: I increased this as an answer because it works for my current need (why I was looking for this). I was needing to `camelize` a field name for Stimulus and to keep with naming conventions per docs the first letter should be `lower`. https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/reference/targets#naming-conventions

Answer (score 3):

My other answer modifies the existing string, this technique does not:

```
str  = "Hello World"
str2 = str.sub(str[0], str[0].downcase)

str  #=> "Hello World"
str2 #=> "hello World"
```

Comment: Your two answers, which are a millimeter apart, should be consolidated into one answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I thought the use of `sub` and assigning to a new variable warranted this to be a (if ever so slightly) distinct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "Hello World"
str.sub!(/^[[:alpha:]]/, &:downcase)
str #=> "hello World"
```

or

```
str = "Hello World"
str2 = str.sub(/^[[:alpha:]]/, &:downcase)
str2 #=> "hello World"
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "Hello World"

str = str[0,1].downcase + str[1..-1] #hello World
```

Of course, you can do it more inline too or create a method.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = 'Hello World'

puts string[0].downcase #This will print just the first letter in the lower case.
```

*Incase you want to print the downcase of first character with rest of the strings use this*

```
string = 'Hello World'
newstring = string[0].downcase + string[1..-1]

puts newstring
```

Answer (score 1):

### String#downcase_first (Rails 7.1+)

Starting from `Rails 7.1`, there is a [String#downcase_first](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-downcase_first) method:

> Converts the first character to lowercase.

For example:

```rb
'If they enjoyed The Matrix'.downcase_first # => "if they enjoyed The Matrix"
'I'.downcase_first                          # => "i"
''.downcase_first                           # => ""
```

**Sources:**

- [String#downcase_first](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-downcase_first).
- [ActiveSupport::Inflector#downcase_first](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-downcase_first).
- [Add String#downcase_first method](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/45827).

Comment: Best answer for current version of RoR!